# How do I get the previously active index of a slide using Swiper.js?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I am able to get the current slide index using `this.realIndex`, as shown in the [documentation](https://swiperjs.com/api/#methods), but `this.previousIndex` is not yielding the realIndex of the previously active slide. Instead, it offers the equivalent of the `activeIndex`, as reflected when the slider loops. How can I get the `realIndex` of the previously active slide? Is this a bug in Swiper? Does this maybe need to go into local storage?

Here is a pen with me logging the slide indexes to the console. Notice how `previousIndex` does nothing useful: https://codepen.io/thenomadicmann/pen/GRRPeWG?editors=1111

Comment: the answer of @neevany seems to work, and is probably the only way. The _problem_ is, that when the event is fired. In your function the properties are already set, to the new values. You can test this by executing `console.info(mySwiper.realIndex, mySwiper.previousIndex, mySwiper.activeIndex)` in the console before transitioning. The values are correct.

Comment: @winner_joiner: Agreed, neevany's answer seems to work surprisingly. I thought maybe it would work only going one direction but seems to work when going backward and forward. Either way, this seems like a bug so I'll be sure to report it on Github. I will award neevany the bounty tonight once I am able.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@neevany was close and got me on the right track. However, for anyone looking to access previousIndex within a looped Swiper using the slideChange event, you'll need to correct for not only the -1 index issue he described, but also for the double slideChange event that occurs when the swiper loops. Code below:

```
// Have to use previousIndex in this fashion due to a bug in Swiper.js as of 11/21/19
let previousIndex = this.previousIndex - 1;
if ( previousIndex == -1 ) {
    previousIndex = 0;
} else if ( previousIndex == document.querySelectorAll( '.swiper-slide' ).length ) { // When swiper loops, slideChange gets fired twice and messes up animations. This prevents it from doing so.
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`this.previousIndex - 1` should give you the `realIndex` of the previously active slide, one catch is, if `this.previousIndex - 1` value is `-1` which means there is no previously active slide, i.e the swiper in just initialized and no swipes have been done yet. this is because `this.previousIndex` is [initialized](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/blob/master/package/src/components/core/update/updateActiveIndex.js#L7) with `activeIndex` when the swiper is initialized.

Comment: This is mostly correct and put me on the right path, so I will award the bounty. However, for those looking to utilize previousIndex in a loop as of 11/21/19, you'll need to be a little more clever to not only avoid the -1 index issue, but also correct for the slideChange event firing twice when the slider loops (code below):

Answer (score 0):

For me the previous answers didn`t help.
I created a function which stores the swiper.realIndex in a variable. Then I just update the variable on pagechange.

```html
var previousIndex;
function getPreviousIndex(){
  previousIndex = swiper.realIndex;
};

getPreviousIndex();
swiper.on('slideChange', function () {
  getPreviousIndex();
});
```